# How to stop the Delphi compiler on a specific warning code?

Tags: delphi

I'd like the compiler to stop on a given warning, like if it was an error.

The goal is to force taking into account warnings that could be really harmful to the code (not every warning is equal regarding severity)

For exemple, I'd like the compiler to stop on such warnings:

- Result may not be initialized
- Usage of a deprecated method
- ...

I didn't find any option in the IDE, maybe in the command line compiler?

Delphi 10.3.2

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is documented: [Warning messages (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Warning_messages_(Delphi))

You use the compiler directive

```
{$WARN identifier ERROR}
```

to treat the warning named `identifier` as an error. The documentation page contains a list of all possible warnings. For instance,

```
{$WARN NO_RETVAL ERROR}
```

will treat

```
W1035 Return value of function '%s' might be undefined
```

as an error.

**Update:** As [Sertac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243614/sertac-akyuz) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248514/how-to-stop-the-delphi-compiler-on-a-specific-warning-code/58248579#comment102867932_58248579), you can also enable this setting globally for the project using **Project Options**, **Bulding**, **Delphi Compiler**, **Hints and Warnings**, **Output warnings**.

Comment: Also in compiler options -> hints and warnings -> output warnings -> "return value of function might be undefined": [false|true|error].

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Very true. I'll add that information.

Comment: See also [How to treat warnings as errors in Delphi 10.2 while settings some warnings to False](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61497184/576719).