# How to treat warnings as errors in Delphi 10.2 while setting some warnings to False

Tags: delphi

In Delphi 10.2 there is this option to treat warnings as errors (Project options -> Delphi Compiler -> Hints and Warnings -> Output warnings). The optiona are `True`, `False` and `as errors`.
When set to `as errors` the compiler will treat every warning as an error, making the build fail. For me, this is essential as I want my build server to fail on any warning (I am using a Microsoft Azure DevOps build pipeline).

The problem is that when I set any of the listed warnings to a non-default value (for instance, when I set  `Platform Symbol` to `False` to ignore any platform symbol warnings), the `as errors` settings does not work anymore. All warnings are then outputted as normal warnings, instead of errors (except for the `Platform Symbol` warning in this example of course).

I know that I can use the `$WARN <identifier> OFF` directive to disable a specific warning, and that does respect the `as errors` setting, but this directive has local scope, so that means I have to add it to every unit that has this warning. I rather use a solution that has global scope and works for the whole project.

My question:
How can I let the compiler treat warnings as errors and disable some warnings globally?

**Update 1**

The warning that is still reported as a warning when `Output warnings` is set to `True`, while some warnings are set to `False` is the `W1029 Duplicate constructor ... with identical parameters will be inacessible in C++`. In my case, the code uses platform specific symbols so I set the `Platform Symbols` warning to `False`, since I am targetting Windows only.

**Update 2**

To clarify my situation: My code has two warnings:

- Platform symbol warning
- Duplicate constructor warning

I use the following settings:

- `Platform Symbol` warning is set to `False`, all others have the default value
- `Output warnings` is set to `As errors`

The result:

- The `Platform Symbol` warning is muted (as expected)
- The `Duplicate constructor` warning **is still output as a warning** instead of as an error.

When I set `Platform Symbol` warning to `True`, the `Platform Symbol` warning *does* get treated as an error and stops compilation.

Comment: Either this is a bug and you should file a bug report, or this is by design and you should file a feature request to change it. Either way, [file a ticket](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior in 10.2. Output warnings = as errors. Platform symbol = false. My test case: `var A: Integer; TFileOpenDialog.Create(nil); Application.Tag := I;`. When I compile in IDE it fails with *E1036 Variable 'I' might not have been initialized*. When I set Platform symbol to true then I get *E1002 Symbol 'TFileOpenDialog' is specific to a platform*. You mentioned build pipeline in your question. Maybe the issue is in how you invoke the compiler from command line.

Comment: @PeterWolf I also have this behaviour in the IDE on my development machine. I am using msbuild to build it on a build server.

Comment: @R.Beiboer Could you try my minimal reproducible example or provide one yourself? I've got a typo there (`var A`). Fixed: `var I: Integer; TFileOpenDialog.Create(nil); Application.Tag := I;`

Comment: @PeterWolf I tried your example and indeed you are right, in that specific case it is working as expected. Perhaps is has something to do with the warning I am seeing. This  is the 'W1029 Duplicate constructor with identical parameters will be inacessible from C++" warning. I supsect this warning is generated during link time, perhaps that is the issue here?

Comment: @R.Beiboer "duplicate constructor" is not a platform-specific warning, it is a warning against Delphi/C++ interoperability and affects any platform you compile your Delphi code for, if you have C++ output files enabled. The warning means your Delphi code contains multiple class constructors with different names but the same parameters. In the resulting C++ `.hpp` file that the Delphi compiler produces, constructors are renamed to match the class type, but having duplicate constructors with the same signature will be illegal C++ code, so the compiler won't emit declarations for the duplicates.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that warning is not a platform warning. It is just that my code also has the `Platform Symbol` warning, that is why I wanted to 'mute' that warning (Windows app). But I want all other warnings to be treated as errors. It turns out that when I mute the `Plaform Symbol` warning and I set `Output Warnings` to `As Errors`, the `Duplicate Constructor` warning is still not treated as an error. When I 'unmute' the `Platform Symbol` warning, the `Platform Symbol` warning  *does* get treated as an error (and compilation stops before it can handle the `Duplcate Constructor` warning).